# GAS ClientHandler and Dateboxes

Tags: google-apps-script

Are Dateboxes not supported by the ClientHandler?

This code gives me error "Cannot find method setValue(object)":

var dateTimeNowHandler = app.createClientHandler()
    .forTargets(app.getElementById('DateCompleted')).setValue(new Date());

Is there something I missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you notice, the setValue() function of a client handler takes a boolean as argument whereas the setValue of the DateBox accepts a Date as an argument. The setValue() function is intended for widgets such as checkboxes

So, your code won't work.

The documentation also says

> method setValue(value)
>
> A directive to set the boolean value of the widgets this handler is targeted to.
>
> This will fail if the widgets being targeted do not support having a boolean value set.

Comment: OK, you're right. Any workarounds for handling DateBoxes using ClientHandler?

Comment: what is the purpose of this ? would you like to give some details ? Does it have to show today's date ? is the handler on the datebox or somewhere else ?

Comment: It could show today's date and probably another.  The handler is on another widget, a button.

Thanks Serge.

Comment: You should be able to use a ServerHandler instead. It will be a little slower to execute, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround could be to use 2 dateBoxes, one `visible` and the other `invisible`, both on a same panel.  A client handler on an button (as you said it was) could trigger the visible/invisible cylcle. I every case only one of them will be visible and they will occupy the very same place in your Ui.
The first one could have some preset value and the second one another preset value (or left empty).

The only tricky thing to do is to handle these 2 values correctly afterwards, ie choose the right one to get the useful value...  Since I don't know the final purpose of this I can't go further in my suggestion (which is indeed just a suggestion :-).

EDIT : if ever you use this suggestion you could have a look [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178836/how-to-know-which-ui-element-is-in-focus) that offers a nice way to know where the e.parameter comes from... I just didn't think about it !