# Get selected checkbox without knowing checkbox name (generated dynamicaly)

Tags: dynamic, checkbox, google-apps-script

I am working on an add-on for the new google sheets and seem to have hit a problem. I am dynamically generating x number of checkboxes for a user to select. When the user selects some boxes and submits, I am submitting this data to a server handler. However, I can't find a way to get out which  checkboxes were selected as I don't know their names. The names are dynamically generated and represent of the ID of the content to retrieve for the user.

Is there any way to find out which checkboxes have been checked on the server side when the name of the checkboxes isn't known?

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting the element's name, set the id to the same as the name and ensure each checkBox has a click handler. Then use:

```
var source = e.parameter.source;
```

which returns the id of the clicked element.

The examples given by Srik and Serge insas in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178836/how-to-know-which-ui-element-is-in-focus/11179376#11179376) should hopefully help you. There are a few similar posts. Just search for "e.parameter.source"

You'll also find info in the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/check-box#addClickHandler%28Handler%29).